# Acces backend classes of lotus notes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, lotus-notes

I need to access the backend classes of Lotus Notes from a vb.net Application. Actualy I want to get the COM interface. I could easely do it in c++:

```
...
NOTESSESSIONPtr itfNotesP;
NOTESDATABASEPtr itfDatabaseP;
...
try
{
    hrNotesSession = itfNotesP.CreateInstance(__uuidof(NOTESSESSION));
    hrNotesUiWorkspace = ptrUIWP.CreateInstance(__uuidof(NOTESUIWORKSPACE));
}
...
```

but in vb.net I'm running out of solutions to acheive the samething with lotus.NOTESSESSION and lotus.NOTESUIWORKSPACE from Notes32.tlb

Does someone know what I am missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-msnet/)?  It's a bit old, and there's at least one important thing it doesn't mention, but I think it shows you enough to get started.

The thing it doesn't mention, which might be important for you or not, is that the Domino COM classes are not supported on Win64.  (See this IBM [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454291).)  You will find a few questions here on StackOverflow from people who have had difficulties, and there are answers to get you past the specifi issue in that technote.  And in fact, most of the classes can be made to work, but a few methods in some of the classes simply do not work. And apart from community help, you're on your own because IBM won't answer questions about stuff that isn't supported.

Comment: Well, now I understand more why what I was doing wasn't working. I absolutely need to use _domobj.tlb_ and not _lotus.tlb_. But what is the goal of _lotus.tlb_? And, by the fact it **only** contains interfaces, what does it stands for? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it at the TLB level.  (Well, that's not completely true... But it's been ten years.)  I can tell you, however, that there are COM classes rooted at lotus.NotesSession, and OLE classes with roots at notes.NotesSession and notes.NotesUIWorkspace.  The OLE classes interact with the running Notes client, and therfore they can use the NotesUIWorkspace class and its children.  The COM classes do not interact with a running client. Notes must be installed and set up, but COM-based programs don't require it to be running, so there is no lotus.NotesUIWorkspace class.

Comment: _The OLE classes interact with the running Notes client_ . You just saved me! This is exactly what I'm looking for. As a last question, where can I find the OLE documentation I need to use it? Thanks! accepted answer for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is very poorly documented. There's just a very brief mention of the OLE support in the help database that is included with the Domino Designer client, and that doc is oriented toward VB6 usage.  In other words, it hasn't been updated in a long time.  Here's a link to an on-line version of that help database.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_USING_NOTES_CLASSES_IN_VISUAL_BASIC.html

Comment: On the left of the page linked above, you will see a link to "LotusScript classes A-Z".  All the NotesUI... classes are covered there, as well as the back-end classes.  The differences between LotusScript and VB are pretty minimal -- at least with respect to VB6 -- so you should be able to work out what you need.  Do read the doc for various methods carefully, though, as there will be a few that aren't supported for COM or OLE.